# Android - Expandable Cardviews within Recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to create a RecyclerView that contains cards that can be expanded to show more options. However I cant quite get it to work correctly as I explained here https://i.stack.imgur.com/83vSy.jpg. I think I am really close to the answer but I've hit a wall and I don't know where I'm going wrong with this.

cardAdapter.java

```
public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.JobViewHolder> {
LinearLayout mLinearLayoutOptions;
LinearLayout mLinearLayoutItem;
ValueAnimator mAnimator;

public static class JobViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView homeName;
    TextView homeCity;
    TextView homeSt;
    TextView homeZip;
    ImageView homePhoto;

    JobViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        homeName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_address);
        homeCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_city);
        homeSt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_state);
        homeZip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_zip);
        homePhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_photo);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

List<Homes> homes;

CardViewAdapter(List<Homes> home) {
    this.homes = home;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public JobViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_home_item, viewGroup, false);
    JobViewHolder pvh = new JobViewHolder(v);

    mLinearLayoutOptions = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.homeOptions);
    mLinearLayoutItem = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.homeDetails);
    //expndIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.expand_details);

    //sets up and handles cardview expand
    mLinearLayoutOptions.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    mLinearLayoutOptions.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    mLinearLayoutOptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    mLinearLayoutOptions.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mLinearLayoutOptions.getMeasuredHeight());
                    return true;
                }
            });

    mLinearLayoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mLinearLayoutOptions.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                //expndIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
                expand();
            } else {
                //expndIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
                collapse();
            }
        }
    });
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(JobViewHolder jobViewHolder, int i) {
    jobViewHolder.homeName.setText(homes.get(i).address);
    jobViewHolder.homeCity.setText(homes.get(i).city);
    jobViewHolder.homeSt.setText(homes.get(i).st);
    jobViewHolder.homeZip.setText(Integer.toString(homes.get(i).zip));
    jobViewHolder.homePhoto.setImageResource(homes.get(i).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return homes.size();
}

//code for expanding
private void expand() {
    //set Visible
    mLinearLayoutOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAnimator.start();
}

private void collapse() {
    int finalHeight = mLinearLayoutOptions.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
            mLinearLayoutOptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}


private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);


    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            //Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mLinearLayoutOptions.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            mLinearLayoutOptions.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}
}
```

I want the buttons to correspond to their card so I am assuming that I need to handle the expanding of the cards within the adapter that creates them. Correct me if i am wrong but I feel like I need to bind them there.

Answer (score 0):

mLinearLayoutOptions will always have the reference of the last view for which onCreateViewHolder was called in the adapter.

Instead, you should store mLinearLayoutOptions in a list and set the index of the item as the view tag.

```
viewList.add(mLinearLayoutOptions);
mLinearLayoutItem.setTag(viewList.size() - 1);
mLinearLayoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (viewList.get((int) v.getTag()).getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            //expndIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
            expand(viewList.get((int) v.getTag()));
        } else {
            //expndIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
            collapse(viewList.get((int) v.getTag()));
        }
    }
});

//code for expanding
private void expand(View view) {
     //set Visible
     view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mAnimator.start();
}

private void collapse(View view) {
    int finalHeight = view.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(view, finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
             //Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
             view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}


private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(final View view, int start, int end) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);


    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            //Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}
```